# Dynamically adding products to ZenCart via CURL

Tags: php, authentication, dynamic, curl, zen-cart

I've done a flash app that creates an high res image. I'm trying to dinamically add this image as a product to ZenCart, via a php script. I thought of accessing the admin via curl, adding a new product and, if successful, returning the newly created product ID.

This would be the login part of the script:

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
$fields = array('admin_name'=>'user', 'admin_pass'=>'pass');
$url = 'http://www.mystore.com/login.php';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,        1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,         $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  1);                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $fields);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){ 
    echo 'error'; 
} else {
    echo $result;
}
```

but unfortunately I'm only getting the following error message:

```
Authorization Required

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.     Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't     understand how to supply the credentials required.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I've tried using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

with no success. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different types of authentication.  The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) mentions:

> CURLAUTH_ANY is an alias for CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST |
>   CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.

So I would go for either `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`

or if that doesn't work or isn't supported try:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST | CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM);`